# Iconic ion-nav-title logo image not displaying

Tags: angularjs, image, ionic-framework, header, png

All I'm trying to do is get my logo image to display in the center of the header. So far everything I have tried hasn't worked, I build everything to my visual studio project and then to my android device and the image just shows up as a little empty box.

I've tried svg and png formats, neither shows. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if android has some kind of issue I need to know about?

By the way, I have no problems viewing the logo when I use the ripple emulator for android, its only when I actually push the app to my android tablet.

```
    <ion-view>    
    <ion-nav-title>
        <img src="../../img/logo.png" style="max-height:50px;" />
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content id="dashboard" class="padding has-header has-subheader">
    </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Comment: your code works good  on my side. If you have saved your image in img folder then *src="img/logo.png"*

Comment: Are you using an actual device or just a simulator? It works on the simulator but not on the device for me.

Comment: it is working nicely on both

Comment: hm.. its not working for my device when I launch it from visual studio to the device, the logo is just a little empty square.

Comment: Nevermind... suddenly its showing up, what the heck. No idea. I didn't even do anything. The only issue is that its not centered for some reason..

Comment: add *$ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');* to your **app.js** file under *.config*